# Could someone explain injectivity and surjectivity of functions?

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

So I'm having trouble with this question and understanding functions. I realize that someone has already posted this question but i didnt see any responses that could help me so i'll try to be more specific in what i need help with.

let $f: \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}: x \mapsto 9x + 1$ where arithmetic is done modulo $12$. 
Show that f is neither injective, nor surjective.

I was wondering how to determine this and if someone could explain injective and surjective as i'm having trouble understanding it

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb Z / 12 \mathbb Z$ is small enough that you can make a table of all of the values of $f(x) = 9x+1 \pmod{12}$.

\begin{array}{c|c}
x & f(x)\\
\hline
   0 & 1 \\
   1 & 10 \\
   2 & 7 \\
   3 & 4 \\
   4 & 1 \\
   5 & 10 \\
   6 & 7 \\
   7 & 4 \\
   8 & 1 \\
   9 & 10 \\
   10 & 7 \\
   11 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{array}

---

$f$ is injective if $f(x) = f(y)$ always implies that $x = y$. To show that $f$ is not injective, you need to find $x \ne y \pmod{12}$ such that $f(x) = f(y) \pmod{12}$. For example, $f(0) = f(4) = 1 \pmod{12}$.

You can look at this more closely.

\begin{align}
   f(x) &\equiv f(y) \pmod{12} \\
   9x + 1 &\equiv 9y + 1 \pmod{12} \\
   9x &\equiv 9y \pmod{12} 
      &\text{Divide by $3 = \gcd(9, 12)$.}\\
   3x &\equiv 3y \pmod 4
      &\text{Multiply by $\dfrac 13 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$}. \\
   x &\equiv y \pmod 3
\end{align}

You can interpret $x \equiv y \pmod 3$ to mean $y = x+3n$ for some integer $n$. To be particular,

$$f(0) = f(3) = f(6) = f(9)$$

$$f(1) = f(4) = f(7) = f(10)$$

$$f(2) = f(5) = f(8) = f(11)$$

---

$f$ is surjective if, for every y in the codomain, there is some $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) = y$. Looking at the table, for example, we see that there is no $x$ such that $f(x) = 2$. So $f$ is not surjective.

You can look at this more closely too. Using more or less the same steps that we used above,

\begin{align}
   f(x) &\equiv y \pmod{12} \\
   9x + 1 &\equiv y \pmod{12} \\
   9x &\equiv y-1 \pmod{12} 
      &\text{Divide by $3 = \gcd(9, 12)$.}\\
   3x &\equiv \dfrac{y-1}{3} \pmod 4
\end{align}

We see that, in order to solve for $x$, we need for $\dfrac{y-1}{3}$ to be an integer. This is precisely what $y \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ means and it suggests that we need to have $y \in \{1,4,7,10\} \pmod{12}$. Looking at the table of $y-$values, we see that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(4)=1=f(8)$, so $f$ is not injective. Further, the equation $9x+1 \equiv 0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}12$. So $f$ cannot be surjective.